# Clicking Stack Exchange button on private beta blanks out page

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, stack-exchange-button, private-beta

I have not been invited to the private beta and have not logged in, and when I open the Stack Exchange dropdown in the top bar on the [Portuguese Stack Overflow private beta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), the entire page is blanked out.

It looks like something is deleting all of the elements. I guess something went wrong when AJAX fetched the rest of the drop down.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: We are aware of the issue - this does not happen if you have been invited to the private beta. Regardless - we are working on a fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a redirect happening on the AJAX call getting data for the site switcher when anonymous / uninvited users were trying to open it on a private beta site, causing this issue

This redirect no longer happens and all your sites are belong to us now.